# Validating large XML files against large XSDs, is there a quick way to do this?

Tags: java, xml, kotlin

I'm trying to quickly validate large XML documents against large XSD's. The XML can be anywhere between 500 to 39000 lines long, and the XSD's are in the region of 2000 - 3000 lines.

The result so far has been horribly slow performance, the initialization of the parser with such large XSDs can take up to 30 seconds, however, this is fine as we can do this once and then just inject it.

But, when it comes to actually using this to validate the XML, depending on the implementation it can take anywhere from 30 seconds to 2 minutes.

This is really odd as a command line tool called xmllint:
`xmllint --schema test.xsd valid.xml`
Is able to do the same job but finishes instantly.

I've tried the JDOM library, the SAXReader method and I've settled on the jdom2 stuff, here's how I'm constructing it:

```
URL xsd = Resources.getResource("test-xml/test.xsd");
XMLReaderJDOMFactory factory = new XMLReaderXSDFactory(xsd);
builder = new SAXBuilder(factory);
```

And here's the parsing in action:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputXml.getBytes());
Document document = builder.build(stream);
```

The builder.build part is the line that needs to be borderline instant.

In terms of the desired solution, I don't mind using C, Kotlin, whatever as long as the output is sensible to read and quick.

Thanks

Comment: It certainly shouldn't take that long, and my suspicion would be that in the course of validation, you are fetching resources from the web: possibly resources such as the schema for the XML namespace on the W3C web site. W3C deliberately slow down such requests in order to discourage them. Find out what resources you are fetching (e.g. by network monitoring) and replace them with local copies.

Comment: Incidentally, I wouldn't describe either your XML files or your XSD files as "large". The sizes seem very modest to me.

Comment: Hey, so we found out the reason, I'm just making that the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer came down to what was actually inside the XSD, specifically the maxOccurs value. At some point the maxOccurs were all set to 4999, which causes a bug reported here: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6483188

If the actual number of maxOccurs isn't relevant to you then you can change the maxOccurs value to "unbounded". Or you can lower your maxOccurs values, on my machine a maxOccurs value of 1000 yielded a result of about 1 second to parse the values, then 99 at about 300ms. With unbounded also being at 300ms.

This is significantly lower than the 50 seconds it took to parse with the maxOccurs value being 4999

Comment: Yes, large finite values of minOccurs and maxOccurs cause problems for the classic FSA-based algorithms. The Saxon schema validator copes with it usually: but not in pathological cases like `(x occurs {1000,2000}) occurs {40, 50}`.